# Errors when searching in Array and location with Android SDK in Parse.com

Tags: android, arrays, parse-platform, location

I'm using Parse.com for an Android app, with de Android SDK.

I'm having problems when trying to query objects based in "whereContainsAll" over an Array, and "whereWithinKilometers" over a Location.

I have 2 objects with class "Menu" with an Array field named "ingredients" with values: ["test", "object1"] and ["test", "object2"] , and a field named "location" with type GeoPoint, both with same value (28.1055674, -15.4168011).

Then I'm doing this query, and I only get 1 result:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Menu");
String[] ingredientsArray = searchDescription.split(" ");  // searchDescription is only "test"
ArrayList<String> ingredientsList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(ingredientsArray));  //ingredientsList is only [test]
query.whereContainsAll("ingredients", ingredientsList);
query.whereWithinKilometers("location", centerGeoPoint, searchRadius);   // centerGeoPoint is a GeoPoint with user location, searchRadius is 5 km
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> dishes, ParseException arg1) {
        // here "dishes" only included 1 object "Menu"
    }
});
```

If a remove the "location" restriction, I get both 2 results:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Menu");
String[] ingredientsArray = searchDescription.split(" ");  // searchDescription is only "test"
ArrayList<String> ingredientsList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(ingredientsArray));  //ingredientsList is only [test]
query.whereContainsAll("ingredients", ingredientsList);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> dishes, ParseException arg1) {
        // here "dishes" only included 1 object "Menu"
    }
});
```

Both objects have same "location" values, I have checked it. If a work with both objects, they include the "location" field with GeoPoint type and exactly the same value, and I can work with this value without problems.

Is there any problem using "whereContainsAll" and "whereWithinKilometers" in the same query? Is it a Android SDK error, a general Parse error? Or is it any error on my tests?

Thanks!